# Jasmine test failing for foreign key

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have 2 tables named `users` and `orders` and models are provided:

```
export type User = {
    id?: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    password: string;
    role: string;
    email: string;
};


export type Order = {
    id?: number;
    userId: number;
    status: string;
};
```

I have a failed test at the time of creating a user:

```
  it('create method should add an order', async () => {
    

    const result = await store.create({
        id: 1,
        userId: 1,
        status: 'open',
    });

    expect(result).toEqual({
        id: 1,
        userId: 1,
        status: 'open',
    });
});
```

The error stack:

```
1) Order Model create method should add an order
  Message:
    Error: Could not add new order for user ID 1 for Error: error: insert or update on table "orders" violates foreign key constraint "orders_user_id_fkey"
```

Obviously, the issue is there is no user exist in the database to make an order. So, as a solution I tried to create a user in this test, but, that breaks the order tests in the users_spec.ts file.

How do I write this test correctly?

Comment: This seems less of a question about Jasmine and more about your test context and environment. I'm guessing your current set up doesn't involve creating a new database and seeding it with the necessary records before each test case is run (or alternatively resetting the state after each run). If it did, you'd be able to create that dummy user and for that test case to not affect any others.

Comment: If I create a dummy user in the same method, the other tests are failing. So, I need to understand why does this happen. An example will be helpful in this case.